# AzerothCore (ZhengPeiRu21) Playerbots module not compiling correctly

Tags: azerothcore

I have been trying to get the ZhengPeiRu21 playerbot module (https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/mod-playerbots) to compile without success. I use the correct tree of azerothcore as described in the readme.md for this: https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/Playerbot

The Cmake process runs without issues, but when I run my compilation I a lot of errors on the playerbot module.

some examples:

```
22>C:\...\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-playerbots\src\ChatFilter.cpp(166,47): error C2039: 'GetTargetIcon': is not a member of 'Group'
22>C:\...\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\src\server\game\Entities\Player\Player.h(59,7): message : see declaration of 'Group'
22>PlayerbotAI.cpp
22>C:\...\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-playerbots\src\RandomItemMgr.h(20,6): warning C5257: 'EquipmentSlots': enumeration was previously declared without a fixed underlying type (compiling source file C:\Users\Jvandeneeckhout\Downloads\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-playerbots\src\GuildTaskMgr.cpp)
22>C:\...\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-playerbots\src\GuildTaskMgr.cpp(504,5): error C2065: 'PlayerbotsDatabasePreparedStatement': undeclared identifier
22>C:\...\AC\pb\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-playerbots\src\GuildTaskMgr.cpp(504,42): error C2065: 'stmt': undeclared identifier
```

(part of the path has been replaced by '...' for readability)

The C2065 is the most occurring but other errors are also present.
The full output file can be made available if this would be helpfull.

I think I'm missing some vital step that is not described anywhere but cannot seem to find it.
My first thought was making a mistake in how modules are created but I was able to:

- Compile and run the core without modules without issues.
- Compile and run the core with compiles other modules without issues.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

- git clone https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/azerothcore-wotlk.git
- move to the modules folder of the downloaded code:
- git clone https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/mod-playerbots.git
- Run Cmake
- click configure
- set TOOLS-BUILD to all
- set MODULE-MOD-PLAYERBOTS to static
- click configure again (no errors)
- click generate
- click open project
- VS 2022 opens on the project
- set project to RelWithDebInfo and X64
- right click BUILD-ALL > clean
- right click BUILD-ALL > Build

expect: compilation without errors
Result: compilation with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pull wrong branch for "azerothcore-wotlk"... When you clone git you need choose playerbot branch not master.
Use `git clone https://github.com/ZhengPeiRu21/azerothcore-wotlk.git --branch Playerbot --single-branch`

Comment: Pulling the playbot branch did the trick.
Thanks for the resolution and the clear instruction.